# remove elements one at a time with a for loop

Tags: jquery

I'm building a list of boxes based on how many images there are with a for loop. 
So if there is 10 images 10 boxes are created.

How can I remove the boxes one at a time based on how many images there are?

(I'm making a image carousel with boxes under the carousel noting how many image there are. I have different carousels so when someone clicks to view a different carousel I need to re populate the boxes)

here is how I'm populating the boxes

```
  for (var i=0; i < get_images.length; i++) {
    $boxCntr = $(".box_counter").first().clone(true);
    $(".box_counter").last().after($boxCntr);       
  }
```

Comment: You said you are creating the boxes based on the number of images. Does something happen to change the number of images after the boxes are created? If so, what? How do you account for that in your existing code?

Comment: Not a very clear question.  Why would you want to remove them one at a time? Does that mean you want them to fade out/shrink staggered instead of all at once?

Comment: I'm making a image carousel with boxes under the carousel noting how many image there are. I have different carousels so when someone clicks to view a different carousel I need to re populate the boxes

Comment: Just a couple of questions, I'm not sure if I understand correctly. You have a carousel with boxes underneath it noting the number of images.  If someone clicks a different carousel, you want to reuse the existing boxes instead of deleting them all.  This means that you may need to remove/add boxes to the `box_counter` collection?

Comment: yes. I'm totally fine with deleting them all I just don't know how

Comment: if I use remove my "boxes" they are gone for ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this

```
 var clone = $('.box_counter').clone(); 
 $('.box_counter').remove();            
 $("body").append(clone);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using jQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('.box_counter').filter(':lt(' + get_images.length + ')').remove();
```

Comment: This totally seems like the right approach but I can't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.box_counter:lt(' + get_images.length + ')').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//$('.box_counter').remove(); // Remove all boxes
$('.box_counter:gt(0)').remove(); // Remove all but one box
```

To synchronize the number of boxes to the number of items that have the .images class:

```
$('.box_counter:gt(0)').remove(); // Remove all but one box
$('.images:gt(0)').each(function(){
    $('.box_counter').last().after($('.box_counter').first().clone(true));
});
```